# How can one detect if a github actions runner is running in ubuntu or windows

Tags: github, operating-system, github-actions

Is it possible to detect which OS a Github actions runner is using? For example, in node one can run `process.platform` to get the OS. Is there something analogous inside of Github actions?

Comment: `echo "$RUNNER_OS"` in a bash `run:` step?

Comment: Thanks, this works on linux, however I don't think I have echo on a windows runner

Comment: You can specify the shell, i.e., use Bash also on Windows; see [this workflow](https://github.com/bewuethr/os-test/blob/main/.github/workflows/ostest.yml) ([example run](https://github.com/bewuethr/os-test/actions/runs/2642672323)).

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I wanted. If you want to expand upon your comments and make an answer, I'll accept it. Otherwise I'll delete the question.

Comment: I can write it up.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is an environment variable `$RUNNER_OS` containing the operating system; you can specify the shell for a `run:` independent of the runner operating system, i.e., you can use Bash everywhere.

For example, this workflow

```yaml
name: OS test

on:
  workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
  printos:
    name: Print OS name for each OS
    strategy:
      matrix:
        os:
          - ubuntu-20.04
          - windows-2022
          - macos-11
    runs-on: ${{ matrix.os }}
    steps:
      - name: Print OS name
        shell: bash
        run: |
          echo "$RUNNER_OS"
```

produces three jobs, with outputs `Linux`, `Windows`, and `macOS`, respectively.

The value is also available in the [`runner`](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/contexts#runner-context) context, which can be used in, e.g., `if` conditionals:

```yaml
      - name: Windows-specific step
        if: runner.os == 'Windows'
        shell: bash
        run: |
          echo "I am a Windows runner!"
```